# How to filter good and bad words based on sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have thanks to Code review got my code reviewed and would like to add more with my code but realized that I managed to do a filter function to check for bad words only but not for good words. This is what I have done so far:

```
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import AbstractSet, Iterable

from database import Database

WORD_BREAKER = re.compile(r"[-'\w]+")


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class BadWords:
    """
    Bad words database.
    """
    combos: AbstractSet[AbstractSet[str]]

    @staticmethod
    def new(bad_words_collection: Iterable[str]) -> "BadWords":
        """
        Create a new BadWords instance.

        :param bad_words_collection: Iterable[str] - The bad words collection
        :return: BadWords - The bad words instance
        """

        return BadWords(frozenset(
            frozenset(WORD_BREAKER.findall(phrase))
            for phrase in bad_words_collection
        ))

    def matches(self, sentence: str) -> bool:
        """
        Check if the sentence contains any bad words.

        :param sentence: str - The sentence to check
        :return: bool - True if the sentence contains any bad words
        """

        words = frozenset(WORD_BREAKER.findall(sentence.casefold()))
        return any(combo <= words for combo in self.combos)


def get_badword_db() -> BadWords:
    """
    Get the bad words database.

    :return: BadWords - The bad words database
    """
    # Mockdata could be:
    # ['test', 't-shirts', 'world', 'beautiful day']
    return BadWords.new([i[0] for i in Database.get_keyword()])


test_match = get_badword_db().matches('test')
```

However my problem is that I want to add including bad words, to add good words as well e.g.

```
['stackoverflow', 'python']
```

meaning that I want to be able to do another check with good words and if it contains **good word** and **no bad** words return `True` else return `False` - However my problem is that how can I combine this code together with good and bad words?

Comment: I did not downvote, however would like you to add research attempts, and only a minimal reproducible example, and improve your wording for the question.

Answer (score -1):

The question is not that clear, but assuming that you like to get sentences that contains *good words* only, check first if not any *bad word* is in your sentence, is thats the case simply check for any *good* one:

```
if any(w for w in s.split() if w in bad_words) == False:
    return any(w for w in s.split() if w in good_words)
else:
    return False
```

##### Example

```
sentences = ['this is a good sentence','this is a bad sentence','this is not a good nor a bad sentence','not a sentence']
good_words = ['good']
bad_words = ['bad']

def good_words_only_check(s):
    
    if any(w for w in s.split() if w in bad_words) == False:
        return any(w for w in s.split() if w in good_words)
    else:
        return False

for s in sentences:
    print(good_words_only_check(s))
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Hello, well kinda similar, Basically I want to do a function that check if a sentence has good word and NOT bad word -> return True, else everything would be False

Comment: Is it not exactly what the example is doing, or do I miss something? Could you provide an example of input and expected output, please.